# Is it OK to dupe hammer the question if gold badge tag is irrelevant to the Question?

Tags: discussion

I came across the question: [How to get rid of white squares on method names? (in SublimeText3, Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42221110/how-to-get-rid-of-white-squares-on-method-names-in-sublimetext3-python). It was originally tagged with [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and [sublimetext3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sublimetext3). Someone marked the Question as duplicate for: [SublimeText encloses lines in white rectangles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354857/sublimetext-encloses-lines-in-white-rectangles).

I initially missed the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag and voted to close the question as the above mentioned Question looked like a right dupe target. Since I am having Gold badge in Python, this Question was dupe hammered. When I noticed that it is having [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag associated to it, I [edited the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42221110/revisions) and removed the Python tag as it was irrelevant to the question.

But now I feel like I misused the privilege (gold badge power) offered to me. The ideal way to handle such scenario would have been to firstly remove the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag and then vote for closing the question (Isn't it?). Since I have already (accidentally) dupe-hammered the Question, should I retract my vote? I think yes, because even though I feel like it is a good dupe target, there is possibility that I may be wrong as I am not an expert of SublimeText. Hence, closing a question with single vote isn't right.

But again, that's my point of view. I want to know the opinion of Community on how should one be dealing with such scenarios. In the mentioned Question, it is obvious that the linked Question is a right dupe target. But my concern is, what if the question was related to some much more complex issue? For example: Programming question, syntactical issue related to some other language. What should one be doing in such case?

Comment: Hammering it open would also invalidate the initial users vote. Leave it as it is, no big deal. If others disagree with the closure, they can reopen it. If not, then all's well in the world.

Comment: Would removing your vote make it *less* of a duplicate?  Hard to believe.  So don't.

Comment: If you feel it is a dupe, leave it. If others disagree, they can reopen.

Comment: It is ok in this case. But my concern is, what if the question was related to some much more complex issue. For example: Programming question, syntactical issue related to some other language. What should one be doing in such case? *(edited the question)*

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri If you're not *entirely* sure it's a duplicate, you shouldn't be voting to close it, dupe hammer or not.

Comment: @Rob We vote to close the question only if we are sure about the reason for closing it (duplicate in this case). And there is a reason why **only** Gold badge holders can close the question with a *single vote* in their respective fields *(because of the knowledge in related field)*. For rest of the users, community asks for 5 votes. That's the SO policy and we should be following it. Here I am trying to know the protocol one should follow when such thing happens. *(I am sure there would be others who might be going through the same dilemma in future)*

Comment: @Rob - The thing is that sometimes you *think* it *might* be a duplicate, but as a gold badge holder you are suppose to **KNOW** if it is. Sometimes I avoid voting because I have more powers than I want to have :-(

Comment: I happily close as duplicate c/c++ question marked with C# tag with my C# gold hammer. I see nothing particularly wrong with it (when I know for sure)

Comment: so, as long as you have at least one gold badge, you can close any question yourself? add tag, close, remove tag

Answer (score 2):

You decided that it is duplicate and voted accordingly. There is nothing wrong with it. You could have also voted as duplicate on top of 4 "unclear" votes and override others' choices with single vote essentially the same way.

If you are not sure if it is indeed duplicate - add a comment instead whether you have gold badge or not.